# Storing a Q_GADGET in a ListModel, it "forgets" about its methods

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a error queue (as a C++ class available as a context property) that can regularly give me a list of `Error` values, which is a Q_GADGET. The gadget has a set of properties, among them `extTimeStamp` which is also a custom Q_GADGET of type `JSDate64` .

So when I get errors, I push the timestamp and messages into a `ListModel` like this

```
function collectErrors() {
   if( errorQueueController.drainable ) {
      for(const error of errorQueue.popErrors()) {
         console.log("Time: " + error.extTimeStamp.asDateTime())
         errorsModel.append({extTimeStamp: error.extTimeStamp, extMessage: error.extMessage})
      }
   }
}
```

As can be seen, I log the timestamp before the `append` and it is also shown in the `Text` delegate, which I connected to the `ListModel`

```
delegate: Text {
   color: "white"
   text: model.extTimeStamp.asDateTime() + ": " + model.extMessage
}
```

But as it turns out, I only see this in the debug output:

> qml: Time: Fri Nov 4 00:43:01 2016 GMT+0100
>
> qrc:/views/DummyView2.qml:352: TypeError: Property 'asDateTime' of object [object Object] is not a function

Even though it is the same value, somehow the properties are gone when queried from within the delegate! I also registered a string converter for my Q_GADGET, and it works at the time of `append`, but when I convert `extTimeStamp` to a string in the delegate, I just get `[object Object]`.

Further, I figured that if I enable `dynamicRoles` for the `ListModel`, everything works as expected. Since the performance is much worse with `dynamicRoles`, the Qt manual discourages from its use, unless it's absolutely required. But I don't understand what it has to do with that, since I'm not changing the data type of roles at all. The `extTimeStamp` role will always be my `JSDate64`-Gadget!

```
// Why does it work with "dynamicRoles: true"?
ListModel { id: errorsModel; dynamicRoles: true }
```

Comment: try  *model.extTimeStamp.asDateTime*  but not  *model.extTimeStamp.asDateTime()* i think this should work)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning your Q_GADGET to a `ListElement`. `ListElement`s have the annoying feature of looking like they hold properties like any other QML object, but they're not properties. They're "roles", and they can only store constant data, like strings. (See [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details)). So it must be automatically converting your Q_GADGET to something that it accepts, but is not really useful to you anymore. I'm not exactly sure why `dynamicRoles` would make it work. Maybe that allows it to be more loose with the type of objects that it stores.

It looks to me like a possible solution for you could be to store the date as a string in your model, instead of as an object.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm merely using `append`, not using the ListElement syntax. Qt's doc seem to indicate that role data that contain objects are supported then. For example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method shows an example that has role data containing a JavaScript array with objects in it.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly its conversion works. The example could indicate that maybe it converts lists to QVariantList and objects to QVariantMap, recursively. That would explain why it loses track of the gadget-ness of my object. How are gadgets represented in QML's JavaScript anyway?

Comment: ListElements can hold arrays of other ListElements. I looked through the source code to verify that the append() function does take the JS object that you pass as an argument and creates a ListElement from it. It actually looks like it first tries to convert the data to a QObject, but uses a QVariantMap if that doesn't work. On the other hand, if `dynamicRoles` is enabled, then I *think* it forces it to use a QVariantMap. So maybe the answer is that ListModels doesn't actually fully support Q_GADGETs, but if you make it a real QObject it might work?